# Window.open opening a tab instead of window in firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, safari

I have a simple HTML layout:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  function test() {
window.open('http://google.com','','menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=545,height=353');
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="test();">Test</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Clicking the button is supposed to open a new window with the specs I specified. However, it's opening a new tab instead in firefox and safari. It works well in chrome. Haven't tested other browsers. Is there something wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. It was because I'm using Firefox and Safari in full screen mode so opening new windows would open a new tab instead to not get out of the full screen mode :)

Thanks